# How can i fix this error ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userData.username')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

.Can anyone can tell me How can i fix this error ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userData.username')

I am building a small app so when you login in app and enter main page than you need to allow permission to get your city name location after frontend gets your city name then it will send your city name to the backend to save your city name in the database and your city name will be saved in database "city is a string" till here everything works fine and its saving my city name into MongoDB database

Now i have a screen in my app so i want that when a user enters that screen then that user will get one random user username and profile pic displayed in frontend note both users should have the same city name in the database the user who requested to server should have the same city as other one random user in the database and i will two same users having same city

Mainpage:

```
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Bottomnavbar from '../../Components/Bottomnavbar'
import TopNavbar from '../../Components/TopNavbar'
import FollowersRandomPost from '../../Components/FollowersRandomPost'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const Mainpage = ({ navigation }) => {
  
  const [userdata, setUserdata] = useState(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      try {
        const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        const userData = JSON.parse(userDataString);
        setUserdata(userData);
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    }

    getUserData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getLocation() {
      try {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        }

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(location);

        let city = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords);
        setCity(city[0].city);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    getLocation();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => { 
    async function sendCity() {
       try {
        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/updateCity', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            city: city,
            username: userdata.user.username
          }),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Success:', data);
      } catch (err) 
        console.error('Error:', err);
      }
    }
    if (userdata && city) {
      sendCity();
    }
  }, [userdata, city]);

console.log(city)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar />
      <TopNavbar navigation={navigation} page={"MainPage"} />
      <Bottomnavbar navigation={navigation} page={"MainPage"} />
      <FollowersRandomPost />
    </View>
  );
}


export default Mainpage
```

Route which updates the city:

```
router.post('/updateCity', (req, res) => {

    const city = req.body.city;
    const username = req.body.username;

    console.log(city)

    console.log(`Updating city for user ${username} to ${city}`);

    User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: username }, { city: city }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'City updated successfully'
        });
    });
});
```

Screen where i want username and profile pic to display:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const SearchUserPage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.userSection}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={profile pic here}
            resizeMode="contain"
            overflow="hidden"
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>User name here</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SearchUserPage
```

Backend code which gets one random user having same city :

```
router.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const city = req.body.city;
  
      console.log(city);
  
      const count = await User.countDocuments({ city: city });
      if (count === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No users found with that city" });
      }
  
      const randomUser = await User.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            city: city,
          },
        },
        {
          $sample: {
            size: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            username: 1,
            profilepic: 1,  // Correct field name
          },
        },
      ]);

      console.log(randomUser[0].username)
      console.log(randomUser[0].profilepic)
  
      res.json(randomUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Try adding a await to your ´setUserData(await response.json());´

Comment: @SeppeWillems Can you give code example

Comment: In your frontend useEffect function to the line setUserData(response.data); add an await statement like this setUserData( await response.data); or make an extra variable like var userData = await response.data and pass that to setUserData(userData);

Comment: @SeppeWillems i did this setUserData(await response.json()) but same errror

Comment: Try to use console.log(response.data) after you awaited it, if this is empty you have a problem with your user fetch

Comment: @SeppeWillems it do not log anything that error came very fast

Comment: You are getting an error, because the initial value of `userData` is `undefined`. Use `userData?.username` instead. Or add `if (!userData) return null` before the actuall return

Comment: not working its logging  LOG  undefined userdata value

Comment: what does `console.log(response.json())` print after fetch operation?

Comment: LOG  [] this is log

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const SearchUserPage = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/user');
        const data = response.json();
        setUserData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  // return null while waiting tor userData to load
  // you can return a spinner or "loading" text instead
  if (!userData) return null;
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.userSection}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{ uri: userData.profilepic }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            overflow="hidden"
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{userData.username}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SearchUserPage
```

Comment: it displaying nothing

Comment: Try now, and it it doesn't work, try checking what's inside `data`

Comment: its logging  LOG  {"_1": 0, "_2": 0, "_3": null, "_4": null}

Answer (score -1):

you're probably also need to check the statut from the response first, since the request can fails with a 404 or 500 HTTP error, fetch will fulfill the promise but the result may not be JSON, like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/user');
        if(response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            setUserData(data); // or data.data i don't know the structure from your api
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    fetchUser();
  }, []);
```

if the data you fetch was coming from an array of object it's better to put a initial empty array like

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
```

Comment: not working same error what code you need to help me fix this issue?

Comment: what kind of data you re trying to fetch ?

Comment: i did this now userdata is logging  LOG  []

Comment: i am trying to fetch username and profile pic both are strings

Comment: I look into your route, you re using get method however there is no body in the GET request, you need to use POST, did you just try to get all the document or a specific one in the document ?

Comment: i am confused i just want to display username and profile pic of one random user who as same city

Comment: Ok, but how do you tell the backend which city you want to search ? you just call fetch with get method without this parameter

Comment: I get the user city name by expo location I also have a city in my user schema which is a string and when a user agrees on the permission of location then the city gets saved in the database

Comment: pls checkout m edited question i have given a schema

Comment: Ok but the issue is on the frontend, there is no code about how you get this city with expo location and pass it to the fetch, that why on the backend if you console.log(req.body.city) it will be undefined, anyway you will need to do a post request.

Comment: i have a different frontend code and different route to get  user city name and save it to backend database

Comment: Ok so you need to set a state for this city  and than pass the city state to this component in order to use it. this won't be easy to solve, you will need to show this route on your frontend

Comment: i will ask new quastion

Comment: you can just update your question and show us the part where you get the city location.

Comment: please give me some time i am writing new quation

Comment: pls checkit out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049866/error-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-userdata-username

Comment: Ok now i see it, so where is the component which you have trouble to fetch ?

Comment: check quaton again where i said "creen where i want username and profile pic to display:" tha t is the component

Comment: So the issue with fetch was in SearchUserPage ? but where is the code did you remove from the component ? And i dont' see the relationship between this component and your mainPage. Ah in a grand-child component ? than which one ?

Comment: @Ohwow i can't here, check again your component is different from your first post, you can see konrad's post have repaste the old code which is different.

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be because you are not accepting json value. Can you try in this way:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const SearchUserPage = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchUser() {
        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/user', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
          body: JSON.stringify({city: 'London'}),
        }).then(response => {
          setUserData(response.json());
          return response.json();
        });
      }

      fetchUser();
    }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.userSection}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{ uri: userData.profilepic }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            overflow="hidden"
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{userData.username}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SearchUserPage
```

Comment: can you give me out full use effect code

Comment: Updated with useEffect()

Comment: WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Already read

Comment: what is printed `console.log(response.json())` after `setUserData(response.json());`

Comment: LOG  {"_1": 0, "_2": 1, "_3": {"error": "No users found with that city"}, "_4": null}
 LOG  {"_1": 0, "_2": 0, "_3": null, "_4": null}

Comment: Then I think you should give a city name to the body of request. Can you try the code again? I updated accordingly

Comment: please give me some time i am writing new quation

Comment: Okay, no problem but let me know if it worked

Comment: pls checkit out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049866/error-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-userdata-username

Comment: Again you are not sending city name with `/user` api since your backend requires it

Comment: city is saved in database what is a better way to do that?

Comment: Yes it is saved in the database but you are checking that request body contains city name with this `const city = req.body.city;` in `/user` api. Also, have you tried my updated code. Try changing `London` with the city name that is in your database

Comment: As you could see it  directly enters to this if `const count = await User.countDocuments({ city: city });
      if (count === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No users found with that city" });
      }
`

Comment: can you give me whole component code also i have two same city in database

Comment: Okay updated my code again but do not forget to change `London` with your city name that is in your database

Comment: I am sorry, for what do you want my email?

Comment: i am very exhausted i can give you my project code its 2 at night here

Comment: you can upload your project to https://snack.expo.dev/ or you can contact me through linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/yakupguly-malikov/

Comment: yep i sent you a connection req